# The exe doesn't run

Tags: java, file, runtime.exec

I used the following Java code for move the file form one directory to another, then execute the file in the destination directory. My code is

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
public class JFileChooserTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filelocation="C:\\Users\\FSSD\\Desktop\\OutPut\\Target";
        File trgDir = new File(filelocation);
        System.err
                .println("file location>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
                        + filelocation);
        File desDir = new File(
                "C:\\Users\\FSSD\\IndigoWorkSpace\\Swing\\test");

        try {
            FileUtils.copyDirectory(trgDir, desDir);
            // FileUtils.copyDirectory(srcDir, trgDir);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Runtime rt=Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            Process p=rt.exec("test\\setup.exe");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
}
```

While i executing this code, the file was successfully moved by i execute this code i got the following error.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "test\setup.exe": CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:431)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:328)
    at JFileChooserTest.main(JFileChooserTest.java:34)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
    ... 4 more
```

Here i used **"setup.exe"**. It is an executable file. while i execute at run time i got the above error. Why it will happens, is any possible to resolve it. Thanks in advance..

Comment: This executable requires admin rights to be run, your java app sbould be run as an admin to be able to execute it.

Comment: Windows 7/Vista and UAC?

Comment: @Maurício Linhares: I'm using Windows 7, if it possible to give the administrator rights via code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using windows 7, when you run your batch process to start your JFileChooser test, right click and select "run as administrator".

Comment: ya,I'm using Windows 7, if it possible to give the administrator rights via code. Here i execute the "setup.exe" at run time. if any other way to do this

Comment: You can't do this with code, but you may be able to execute another batch process and use the /runas command in it for the setup. However if your current user doesn't have admin privs, it's just not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

> The requested operation requires elevation

You do not have the rights to execute this setup. Probably UAC blocks it.

Use the [`runas`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true) command with `Runtime#exec` in Java.

Comment: Not with Java but with Rocky's approach, yes.

Comment: Rocky's processes is suite only If i execute the exe by manually, here i execute the exe through code..is any code to do the "runs as administrator" mode?

Comment: Yes, you can. Windows has a `runas` command which should do what you need.

Comment: Here `Process p=rt.exec("runas /user:... test\\setup.exe");`.

Comment: Try to run in in `cmd` first and then use in Java. Although examine `runas` return code and stdout.

Comment: you mean, first run this .java file in cmd prompt,

Comment: No no, try the runas command in cmd prompt and if this works, put it in Java.

Comment: sadly, i tried to run this, i got "RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - C:\Users\FSSD\IndigoWorkSpace\Swing\test\setup.exe
740: The requested operation requires elevation." error

Comment: C:\Windows\System32>runas /user:FSSD C:\Users\FSSD\IndigoWorkSpace\Swing\test\setup.exe

Comment: So this user has no admin rights. You are out of luck. Maybe you will find somehting more useful in the MS documentation.

Comment: @Michael-O let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2665/discussion-between-bendennison-and-michael-o)